# Reactive Forms: Activate Validation on disabled FormControl

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

it is posible in reactive Forms to force validiation on disabled FormContols?

Comment: You can apply the validator to the form group instead of the control.

Comment: what you tried, can you share your code here.

Comment: you can **not** disable the FormControl and use `[attr.disabled]="condition?true:null"` -see that the attribute disable should be "null" if condition is not fullfilled- (but you loose the power of enable/disable a FormControl)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `readonly` instead of `disabled`.

When you set disabled it's `formcontrol validators` will ignored.

for more info: [disabled input](https://angular.io/api/forms/AbstractControl#disabled)